# Answering your bounty question

Tags: support, bounty, self-answer

I have an open bounty question ([qtcreator can't find qt](https://superuser.com/questions/890118/qtcreator-cant-find-qt)) and solved the problem.

In those cases you answer your own question but mine has open bounty, what will happen to the bounty? I don't think I'll get it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot give yourself a bounty (and its something that would be abused anyway)

Refunding bounties is really on a case by case basis. In theory, once you have offered a bounty, you really arn't meant to get the reputation back

There's a few options here, really. As a one off thing, under exceptional circumstances, we do refund bounties. Posting a detailed, high quality (and repeatable) answer, and explaining your circumstances in a flag is definately one option. In general, bounties arn't meant to be refunded (but of course there's exceptions), so don't make a habit of it -It would really depend on how the mod who handles the flag sees it, and there's no guarantee of a refund.

I usually wait for someone else to answer (or mention that there's a open bounty, and point folk at the right direction on chat!), for reasons for fair play when this happens. I do have rep to burn, so to speak, so...
Seems a much nicer thing to do.